# LDAP/PHP - When to Unbind

Tags: php, ldap

I have around 12 PHP functions, each one makes a call to $ldap_connect which makes use of ldap_bind()

So - does this mean that when I call all functions my ldap server makes 12 ldap binds?

If so - when should the ldap_unbind() function be used? I have tried searching this but nothing fruitful came up, all I seemed to find was "unbind every time" but that isn't really specific. Does that mean put an unbind in all 12 functions just before it returns the data or unbind on my logout page where I also do a session_destroy() ?

Thanks

EDIT: CODE

```
function create_ldap_connection($username, $password) {
$ip = "MY LDAP SERVER";
$port = 389;

/* Binding */


$username = "DOMAIN\\" . $username;

$ldap_conn = ldap_connect($ip, $port) or die("Sorry! Could not connect to LDAP server ($ip)");
ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die ("Couldn't set option version 3");
$starttls = ldap_start_tls($ldap_conn) or die ("Couldn't start secure TLS connection");
$result = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $username, $password) or die("Error: Couldn't bind to server using provided credentials!");

if($result) {
return $ldap_conn;
} else {
die("
Error: Couldn't bind to server with supplied credentials!");
}
}
```

Then I use $ldap_conn = create_ldap_connection($user, $pass);

So, my 2 of my functions would be:

```
function get_user_givenName($ldap_conn, $user_name, $ou) {


$basedn = "MY BASE DN";


$searchResults = ldap_search($ldap_conn, $basedn, $user_name);

if (!is_resource($searchResults))
die('Error in search results.');


$entry = ldap_first_entry($ldap_conn, $searchResults);
$attrs = ldap_get_attributes($ldap_conn, $entry);

return $attrs["givenName"][0];

}

function get_user_cn($ldap_conn, $user_name, $ou) {


$basedn = "MY BASE DN";


$searchResults = ldap_search($ldap_conn, $basedn, $user_name);

if (!is_resource($searchResults))
die('Error in search results.');


$entry = ldap_first_entry($ldap_conn, $searchResults);
$attrs = ldap_get_attributes($ldap_conn, $entry);

return $attrs["cn"][0];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you bind on a connection a previous bind on that connection is "unbound" and replaced with the current bind. So there is no need to use unbind 12 times if you use the same connection.

But when you connect and bind 12 times chances are great that you have 12 concurrent connections to the LDAP-Server which might not really be what you want.

So perhaps you should reconsider the setup of your functions to call `ldap_connect` (and `ldap_bind`) once and then use that connection 12 times instead of creating that connection 12 times. That might reduce the overhead.

A good example would be something like this:

```
$con = ldap_connect([$params]);
ldap_bind($con, [remaining params]);

ldap_[otherfunc]($con, [remaining params]);
```

A bad example would be something like this:

```
function connect() {
    $con = ldap_connect([params]);
    ldap_bind($con, [remaining params]);
    return $con;
}

ldap_[otehrfunc](conncet(), [remaining params]);
```

That would create a new ldap-connection on every call to `connect()`.

To change that into a "good" example you should change that as follows to use the connection multiple times:

```
$con = connect();
ldap_[otherfunc]($con, [remaining params]);
```

Comment: Thanks heighlandreas! This explain things a lot more clearly.

So, I have a function, create_connection() which is the only time ldap_bind() is called. This function is in a variable, $ldapconn and then in all my other php functions I use $ldapconn as input - is this the correct method or is this creating concurrent connections?

Comment: Can you update the question with some code snippets? That would make it easier ;)

Comment: Updated. It looks like I am doing your "bad example" but I see the bind doesn't actually have to be part of the initial connection function which is called over and over?

Comment: As far as I see it you are doing it the "right" way ;) You call ```create_ldap_connection()``` once and assign the return value to a variable. Then you pass that variable (containing just the ldap-connection, not the function itself) to the other functions. So you have a connect and bind once when calling ```create_ldap_connection()``` and then you are using that connection. Looks perfectly safe to me ;-)